# java regex operation for extracting first word and counting numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regex operation to use in Java that will extract the first word, count the number of numbers on the line, and join the two together separated by a comma.

So, for example:

```
"GAMESTATS  1(foul) 4(goals) 2(assists)"
```

would be converted to:

```
"GAMESTATS , 3"
```

because the first word is "GAMESTATS", and there are three numbers ("1", "4" and "2") on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
String s = "GAMESTATS 1(foul) 4(goals) 2(assists)";
String output = s.split(" ")[0] + "," + (s.split("\\d+").length - 1);
```

or, probably more efficient:

```
String output = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")) + "," + (s.split("\\d+").length - 1);
```

Comment: yes that was eaxtly what i needed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] srt = line.split()
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append(srt[0]);
sb.append(",");
int sum =0;
for(int i=1;i<srt.length;i++){
  sum += // You will need to use a pattern like this [0-9]+ to extract the num
}
```